# PHP - WordPress - get commenter credentials

Tags: wordpress, comments

On my website all users have to be logged in to comment on a blog-item.
If a comment is placed I want the users first and last name placed by their comment.

I have no idea how to do this. If I use `get_comment_author` it shows me Anonymous. The codex tells me this:

> Displays the comment author name; that is, the one supplied by the commenter. If no name is provided (and "User must fill out name and email" is not enabled under Discussion Options), WordPress will assign "Anonymous" as comment author.

But the user is logged in. So I should be able to place a name there.

Any thoughts?
M.

Comment: Why are you using get_comment_author? Because it looks like the users are registered on your website and not random people...

Comment: I would use this to get your users details after they have commented http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

Comment: I tried this but the problem is that it doesn't stay next to the post if another user is logged in! The post get's the name of the current_user even if I don't use `$current_user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
if ($comment->user_id) {
    $user=get_userdata($comment->user_id);
    echo $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name; }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you take a closer look at the comments table to see if it's an isolated comment or weather all comments are Anonymous? I would look at that table and do some test posts to see weather right data is coming in.